# json_decode() started returning NULL

Tags: php, curl

I have PHP script that uses json_decode() to convert a curl response into an associative array. The script worked fine for about a month. Without making any changes, json_decode() started returning NULL.

I checked, an curl is working fine, it returns a JSON string, but when I pass the response to json_decode() I get NULL.

According the PHP manual, json_decode() returns NULL when the recursion limit is exceeded. I changed the recursion limit value in the ini file, but that didn't work.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl); 
$decode = json_decode($response, true);
```

I should note that the the curl response string is pretty big.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the content of `$response`?

Comment: and what does `json_last_error()` output?

Comment: I'm getting JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Probably, some hidden characters are messing with your JSON string

```
$decode = json_decode(utf8_encode($response));
```

Also if there is any string padding around your JSON string, json_decode will return NULL so it would be best to trim it before using it in `json_decode`, especially if you're pulling the data from non-PHP sites.

```
$response = trim($response);
$decode = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Neither trim nor utf8_encode worked. I tried using json_last_error() as per ceejayoz suggestion above, and I'm getting a JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR error. It sems that the problem is in the response from the server.

Comment: JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR indicates that the error is in control characters. This usually happens when there's an incorrect encoding. The error is probably coming from how the response is presented from the url as you've rightly said

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the json_last_error() function.

Answer (score 0):

By using the json_last_error() function as suggested i got my question answered. the problem persists, but it's beyond my control, and I know what the issue is. Thank you all.